How do I link zooming on multiple plots of the same dataframe with different axis ranges?
I am making multiple plots based on the same data source, the markers on each plot represent the same set of samples. If my data is in a table or dataframe, the different plots may use different columns of the dataframe but each plot will contain one marker per row of the dataframe.
How do I link the two subplots of 'A vs B' and 'C vs D' so when I zoom into a selection on 'A vs B', it will automatically zoom in to the corresponding points on 'C vs D' as well?
Below is sample of data, the keys of 'a, b, c, d' are all linked through the key of 'time'. Currently, the two subplots are shown but I do not know how to link the zoom feature between the two subplots via 'time'.
import plotly.subplots as subplots
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'b': [10, 15, 13, 17, 20],
    'c': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'd': [8, 12, 10, 14, 16],
    'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})
fig = subplots.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
fig.add_trace(x=df['a'], y=df['b'], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(x=df['c'], y=df['d'], row=2, col=1)
fig.show()

I have tried sharing the x- and y- axis. However, due to the difference in scale between columns it negates the purpose of the plots.

Does this answer your question? how can I get all the subplots to zoom and pan the same way on the X axis, with plotly

I know you ideally would like to link both x and y axes of each plot but I think two or more plots can only share a single axis at a time, see my answer or this link for an example.

I am not looking to link an axis (either x or y). Is there a way that when I select data points from rows 1-3 in a data frame in Plot A, will it zoom into the data points from rows 1-3 in Plot B? Both Plot A and Plot B have different data and do not share axis. Thank you.

Oh, you want the points from each respective subplot to be correlated? The only idea that comes to my mind is to subtract an offset from positions of the data points in one set so they match the positions of the other set and then set the axis tick labels to be the values you actually want those points to have (value + offset). But the zoom feature goes off of plot position relative to shared axis, not shared marker.

Alright see if my new answer suffices. Also, in your scenario, the length of the data for each plot has to be the same because you're wanting each respective point to be correlated in the zoom (assumes there is an existing point with which to correlate for each point). Just making sure I'm understanding you correctly.

Shared axis is all it takes, I believe.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create subplots with shared x-axes
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)

# Add traces to the subplots
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[10, 15, 13, 17, 20], name='Plot 1'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], y=[8, 12, 10, 14, 16], name='Plot 2'), row=2, col=1)

# Show the figure
fig.show()



As mentioned above, this solution does not work in this circumstance because the difference in scale between the x-columns is quite large. What if x1=[1,2,3,4,5] and x2=[500,501,502,503,504,505]? The only shared data between the datasets is column 'time'.

If the only shared data between the two sets is time and time is not even plotted in either of your plots then what do you mean by wanting the zoom for each plot to be correlated? Correlated on the basis of what? I'm confused with your data and desired outcome.

I added the 'time' column as a linker. But Row 1-3 of Plot A can also correspond to Row 1-3 of Plot B. Unfortunately I do not think that there if functionality to support linking the two plots with a 5th series as of yet. This is so far, the best solution.

The zoom and selection features of plotly work on a basis of the x and y positions of the plot. So if two plots share an axis via fig = make_subplots(shared_xaxes=True) the zoom for one plot's x-axis will apply in the other(s). But this doesn't work for shared markers as the OP desires.
The closest you could get to that, as far as I have thought, is to create an offset between the values of the markers of one plot so that the plotted values are in the same range and each marker is visibly connected then add the offset back to display for the tick labels.
Here's an example where the tick text differs from the tick values for data with drastic range difference:
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x2 = [501, 502, 503, 504, 505]
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create subplots with shared x-axes
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)

# Add traces to the subplots with x2 offset taken out
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[10, 15, 13, 17, 20], name='Plot 1'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[1, 5, 3, 7, 2], name='Plot 2'), row=2, col=1)

# Add the real x2 values as the ticktext
fig['layout']['xaxis'].update(showticklabels=True)
fig['layout']['xaxis2'].update(tickvals=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ticktext=['501', '502', '503', '504', '505'])


fig.show()


